# Error al abrir una base de datos en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

No sé a que se deba el siguiente error:

```
USE BD_INVENTARIO
GO

Mens. 945, Nivel 14, Estado 2, Línea 1
No se puede abrir la base de datos 'BD_INVENTARIO', porque no es posible tener acceso a archivos, o la memoria o el espacio en disco son insuficientes. Consulte el registro de errores de SQL Server.
```

Y en el explorador de objetos no puedo desplegar dicha base de datos **(1 y 2)**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuado pongo en propiedades me sale lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En internet me sale algunas consultas para poder solucionar aparentemente un problema de usuarios no habidos en bases de datos provenientes de otros servidores usando el comando `"USE"` , pero como ven no puedo usar ese comando.

Por favor alguna guía para solucinar el incidente.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Este problema da cuando has movido la carpeta del base de datos a otro disco duro o carpeta

Comment: Hola, y qué haría para solucionar dicho problema, al parecer es una base de datos proveniente de otro servidor y entiendo que ocurrió un inconveniente con el proceso de restauración.

Comment: Pero si es tu caso que lo cambiaron de carpeta así te preparo la respuesta??

Comment: `Consulte el registro de errores de SQL Server` <-- Qué encontraste al revisar?

Answer (score 0):

Este error lo puedes solucionar de 4 maneras que son las siguientes:

1. Si es posible, agregue más espacio en el disco duro eliminando los archivos innecesarios del disco duro o agregando un disco duro nuevo de mayor tamaño.
2. Verifique si la base de datos está configurada para crecer automáticamente.
3. Verifique si la cuenta que intenta acceder a la base de datos tiene suficiente permiso para realizar la operación.
4. Asegúrese de que los archivos `.mdf` y `.ldf` no estén marcados como de solo lectura en el nivel del sistema de archivos del sistema operativo.

Puedes leer mas sobre este error en este link [Sql server](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/02/sql-server-fix-error-945-database-cannot-be-opened-due-to-inaccessible-files-or-insufficient-memory-or-disk-space-see-the-sql-server-error-log-for-details/)